# SAS DDE write multiple line in cell

Tags: sas, dde

I want to insert multiple line into one cell, but DDE does't work with directly put '0A'x.

```
filename xlSheet1 dde "Excel|c:\test.xlsx.Report!R1.C1:R1.C3" notab;
data _null_;
    file xlSheet1;
    a = "test";
    b = cat("&sysdate","-", "&systime");

    c = translate("Hello World", '0A'x, " ",);

    put a '09'x b '09'x c ;
run;
```

Only first part write in the cell.

Any good advice?

Comment: I don't think your filename is specified correctly there, does that line generate an error of any kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, thought there would be an easier way, but this is the simplest thing I could get working:

```
filename xlSheet1 dde "Excel|sheet1!R1C1:R1C1" notab;
data _null_;
    file xlSheet1;
    a = cat('="line1 " & Char(10) & "line2"');
    put a;
run;
```

Basically convert your value into a formula.  Use the formula to append the text together and use excel to create the carriage return.

For this to work the cell also needs to be formatted with the 'wrap text' option.  In fact, if you go to any cell in excel and use alt-enter to manually create a carraige return, you will notice it automatically turns on 'wrap text' for you so I don't think this part is optional.